# React-Native get pov values from google streetview

Tags: react-native, iframe, webview, google-street-view

I need to access the POV values from google streetview.

Currently I have an iFrame nested inside a WebView, and if I use the WebView to get me the url, it comes back blank.

```
WebViewNativeEvent.url => returns 'about: blank'
<WebView
    ref={this.webview}
    onNavigationStateChange={WebViewNativeEvent => this.onNavigationStateChange(WebViewNativeEvent)}
 rest of webview props...
 source={<iframe containing url to embed API streetview/>}
 />
```

I believe all the values I need are in the url which is changing (?) within the iFrame, but I'm not sure how to access it.

Is it possible to use the inject javascript prop on the WebView to somehow get the updated url from the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try this might help

```
<WebView
   originWhitelist={['*']}
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
   source={{html: `<iframe id="playerFrame" src="https://..." ></iframe>`}}
   onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
      // navState.url ...              
   }}
/>
```

Parse url for accessing params

```
var regexp = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g;
var params = {};
var check;
while (check = regexp.exec(url)) {
  params[check[1]] = check[2];
}
```

Result will give you

```
Object {
  "param": "value",
  "param": "value",
  "param": "value",
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I am trying to get the url to parse, I don't have it yet.

Comment: I have updated my answer check if it helps for accessing url